# Bootstrap carousel - how to use an image as background that is LARGER than the carousel?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I've been beating myself this weekend to get around this one.
I have a site that uses Bootstrap 3.0 and a Carousel with background images, and I've managed to reproduce my question in a small fiddle.
I have a max-heighted div with an image inside. The image will typically be larger than the div (at least in height).  I'm using the `img-responsive` class from bootstrap to make sure that in mobile browsers the image scales down.  That is the reason why I max-height the div and don't put a fixed height on it.

My questions is: how can I get the image to vertically align to the middle?
I've tried:

- Adding classes `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, but a table cell cannot have a max-height.
- Aligning things vertically but none seem to work.
- Setting a negative margin on the image using javascript, but that makes the div smaller as well as the div uses the image to size itself.
- Using css background instead of an inline image. This does not make the div be (at most) as large as the image and doesn't allow responsive growing/shrinking.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SabbeRubbish/dZQ26/4/

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div id="frame" class="item active">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" 
         class="img-responsive" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone recommend me good and clean ways to get the image to center vertically?  Or tell me what the hell I'm doing wrong? :-)
Thanks.

PS: why center vertically? If the page is very wide, there is a large clip area as the image grows with the page.  It is nicer to show the middle of the picture rather than the top.

Answer (score 2):

is this something closer to what you are trying to achieve ?

```
#frame {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    max-height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px; /* Remove this line */
    padding: 15px 0px; /* Add this line to always have height on the div */
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
    background-position: center center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rrEYJ/

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments you can also use `background-size: contain;` to have the entire image inside the #frame element. You will probably have to also use `background-repeat: no-repeat;` in that case.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrEYJ/1/

**EDIT2:**

Based on your comment I did some research and apparently the background-size property can be set in percentages also. Based on this new information see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rrEYJ/3/

**EDIT3:**

The css had a min-height property that's why the div wasn't changing it's height. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrEYJ/4/

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can also use `background-size: contain;` if you want to have all the image inside `#frame`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! However :-) I don't want the image to be resized to its height. I want the image to span the entire width. The carousel will look ugly (with extra borders to the sides) if the image is shown entirely. See the updated fiddle (red is bad): http://jsfiddle.net/SabbeRubbish/rrEYJ/2/

Comment: Thank you!  This makes the image center in the div.  Great!  But now, when shrinking the page, the div no longer shrinks, revealing red zone... :-)

Comment: That makes the height of the div problematic. :-)  Now the height is paragraph size + 15px padding, not 100px anymore.  The div needs to be 100px at all times, up to the point where the image's height becomes smaller than 100px,  then it needs to shrink.  BTW, this is why I abandoned the background-image track.

Comment: I think that is more vertical responsiveness which can only be achieved with javascript. The height of elements in responsive design need to be either auto or maxed to fit the content. This is far from basic responsive stuff.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your replies.  I will need to find out a different way to do things.  Not a fan of Javascript as it may trigger flickering when repositioning items, but I'll see where I get.

Answer (score 0):

Add style for image like this

```
#frame img {
width:auto;
max-height:100px; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!  However :-)  I don't want the image to be resized to its height.  I want the image to span the entire width.  The carousel will look ugly (with extra borders to the sides) if the image is shown entirely. See the updated fiddle (red is bad): http://jsfiddle.net/SabbeRubbish/dZQ26/6/

Comment: we can give image width 100% and height auto, but for #frame you have added 100px max height, and this creating issue

Comment: I need the height to be constrained...  If no max-height, the div becomes larger.  I don't want this.  I want the image to be full width, auto height, but with a viewport not larger than the div.